# ARB_shader_image_load_store - what version of OpenGL and what hardware is required?

Tags: opengl

I'm a bit confused about new OpenGL extensions, what hardware they require and what OpenGL version they require.

In particular it's about the ARB_shader_image_load_store now.
http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_image_load_store.txt

As I understand, this is a feature of OpenGL 4.2 but in the OpenGL dependencies it's written:

```
This extension is written against the OpenGL 3.2 specification
(Compatibility Profile).

This extension is written against version 1.50 (revision 09) of the OpenGL
Shading Language Specification.

OpenGL 3.0 and GLSL 1.30 are required.
```

and further down stuff like

```
This extension interacts trivially with OpenGL 4.0 and ARB_sample_shading.
```

What do these things mean? What Hardware and what OpenGL version is necessary to use such Extensions?

Comment: It used to be an EXT of the same name, it has been promoted to Core in 4.2. But anyway, I wouldn't go around checking versions. Just check for extension support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What do these things mean?

Well, let's take them one by one.

Before we begin, some basic information. OpenGL specifications, whether core or extension, *do not care* about what hardware something runs on. They're not interested in that. They don't define *hardware*. You can't look at an extension spec and know a priori what hardware it will function on. If you want to find that information out, you're looking in the wrong place.

Furthermore, you have to understand something about extension specifications. An OpenGL extension is like a *diff*; you can't read it in isolation. An OpenGL extension is a document that modifies the OpenGL specification.

> This extension is written against the OpenGL 3.2 specification
>   (Compatibility Profile).
>
> This extension is written against version 1.50 (revision 09) of the OpenGL
>   Shading Language Specification.

A diff file is utterly useless unless you know exactly what file to patch it into, yes? That's the same thing with OpenGL. The extension specification will make references to section and paragraph numbers in the OpenGL specification. But... there are *many* versions of the OpenGL specification. Which one is it talking about?

Therefore, every extension must state which physical document it is referring to. So when this extension says, "Add a new subsection after Section 2.14.5, Samplers, p. 106", it means page 106, section 2.14.5 of the OpenGL 3.2 specification, compatibility profile.

Same goes for the GLSL language specification.

> OpenGL 3.0 and GLSL 1.30 are required.

Now, just because an extension is written *against* a particular version does not mean that this is the minimum version where support for the extension is possible. An implementation could theoretically support it in an earlier version.

This statement says what the minimum version that can *possibly* support it is.

This is not a matter of *hardware*; it is a matter of *language*. The reason 3.0 is the minimum is because this extension refers to concepts that are simply not available in 2.1. Such as integer image formats and so forth. We'll talk a bit more about this in the next part.

> This extension interacts with X.

The "interacts with" statement speaks to optional parts of the specification. What it means is that if "X" and this extension are *both* supported, then certain paragraphs in this specification also exist.

For example, ARB_shader_image_load_store states, "This extension interacts with ARB_separate_shader_objects". If you look towards the bottom, you will find a section titled "Dependencies on ARB_separate_shader_objects". That lists the specific language that changes when ARB_separate_shader_objects is available.

The "interacts trivially with X" statement simply means that the interaction is generally a "remove references to X" statement.  For example, the section on ARB_tessellation_shader/4.0 dependencies state, "If OpenGL 4.0 and ARB_tessellation_shader are not supported, references to tessellation control and evaluation shaders should be removed."

The "trivially" language is just the extension's way of saying, "if X isn't supported, then obviously any references to the stuff X implements should be ignored."

The interaction with ARB_separate_shader_objects isn't trivial because it involves redefining how early depth test works.

The "interacts with" is an alternative to the "are required" wording. The ARB could have simply written it against 4.1 and firmly stated that 4.1 is required. Then there wouldn't have been nearly as many "interacts with" clauses, since none of those things are optional.

However, the ARB wanted to allow for the possibility of hardware that could support GL 3.0 concepts but not others. For example, in the mobile space, shader_image_load_store support could come before tessellation_shaders. That's why this extension has a lot of "interacts with" clauses and a fairly low "required" GL version. Despite the fact that on desktops, you will not find any implementation of ARB_shader_image_load_store paired with a version number less than 4.0.

> What Hardware and what OpenGL version is necessary to use such Extensions?

None of these documents will tell you that. ARB_shader_image_load_store *could* be available on any implementation version 3.0 or greater.

The easiest and simplest way to find out what hardware supports what extensions is to [use the OpenGL Viewer](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/). It has a pretty up-to-date database of this information.

Alternatively, you can use some common sense. ARB_separate_shader_objects allows you to mix and match programs on the fly. This is something D3D has been doing since Direct3D 8. Obviously hardware *could* do it since shaders came into being; OpenGL simply didn't *let you*. Until now.

Obviously ARB_separate_shader_objects is not hardware-based.

Similarly [ARB_shading_language_pack420](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shading_language_420pack.txt) contains many features that D3D has had since forever. Again, there's clearly nothing there that requires specialized hardware support.

ARB_tessellation_shader is obviously something that *does* require specialized hardware support. It introduces two new shaders stages. ARB_shader_image_load_store is the same way: it introduces a fundamental new hardware ability. Now, it is certainly possible that earlier hardware could have done it. But that seems unlikely.

This isn't always the case for every extension. But it is mostly true.

The other thing you should know about is OpenGL version numbers. Since 3.0, the ARB has been good about keeping to a strict version numbering scheme.

Major versions represent fundamental hardware changes. 3.x to 4.x is directly equivalent to D3D10 to D3D11. Minor versions are either making the API nicer (see ARB_texture_storage, something we were *long* overdue for) or exposing previously unexposed hardware features for the same hardware level (ARB_shader_image_load_store *could* have been implemented on any 4.0 implementation, but the ARB just took until 4.2 to write the extension).

So if you have hardware that can run 3.0, it can also run 3.3; if it doesn't have drivers for it, then your driver maker isn't doing their job. Same goes for 4.0 to 4.2.

Comment: I think you should put this text on the OpenGL wiki.

Comment: @datenwolf: [Done.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Extensions#How_to_read) It's not 100% of the text (though it does contain some new material), but it gets the point across.

Answer (score 0):

These things mean how to correctly read extension specification. To read specification you must know how extension interacts with other OpenGL features. And by saying "extension interacts trivially with OpenGL 4.0", it means you must thing of core OpenGL 4.0 feature ARB_sample_shading, and how this extension changes its behaviour.

Because it is in OpenGL Core 4.2 specification,  ARB_shader_image_load_store should be supported on all Shader Model 5 / Direct3D11 hardware (Radeon HD5xxx and up, GeForce 400 and up).

So you can check if your OpenGL version is >=4.2 or check ARB_shader_image_load_store extension presence.

Comment: hey and thanks for this clarification! just one more thing, if OpenGL version >=4.2 is required, why is there written `OpenGL 3.0 and GLSL 1.30 are required.`?