# Usage of GL_ARB_clear_texture throws access violation exception

Tags: opengl

I use OpenGL 4.3 (core).My video card is NVidia Quadro4000 which supports OpenGL 4.3.I decided to try [glClearTexImage](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/clear_texture.txt)() function.I updated GLEW from 1.9.0 to 1.10.0 which has this method mapped.
When glClearTexImage line is entered, Visual Studio throws following exception:

**"Unhandled exception at 0x757AC9F5 in XXXXX_XXXX.exe:0xC0000005:Access violation executing location 0x00000000."**

The code is simple:

```
//...Here the texture is created....

    GLuint clearColor = 0;
glBindTexture   (_target,newTex);
glClearTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &clearColor);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check value of glClearTexImage, e.g.

```
printf("%p\n", glClearTexImage);
```

It's most likely to be NULL. If so, check GLEW_ARB_clear_texture - surely it will be 0 too.

Comment: yep,it is 00000000... But I don't get it.The extension docs say it is written against OpenGL 4.3.I have 4.3 so why the extension is not available ?

Comment: 'written against opengl 4.3' says that this extension requires opengl 4.3 to be present. You're trying opposite - noone promised you that your graphics card/driver supports this specific extension (as well as any others). You have to check for GL_EXTENSIONS string, or GLEW_* variables, to ensure that you have extension - only then you may use it.

Comment: @keltar: No it doesn't. For example, [ARB_enhanced_layouts](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/enhanced_layouts.txt) is "written against OpenGL 4.3", but it explicitly *requires* only "OpenGL 3.1 and GLSL 1.40 or later".

Comment: Okay, so be it. It uses some assumptions and definitions made in specific version. At some point, some extensions may be merged into new spec version - in that case, extension presence check may be skipped. However, using specific GL version requires special initialization phase - it could be easier to stick with low version and just use extensions you need.

Answer (score 2):

No release drivers support any of the recent OpenGL 4.4 features. The closest you're going to get is NVIDIA's *beta* drivers.

Also, if you're going to use a function, you should check to see if the core version/extension is available first.

Comment: The specs actually says this :  This extension is written against the OpenGL 4.3 (Core Profile)

Comment: @MichaelIV: That doesn't mean it is A) part of OpenGL 4.3 or B) is automatically available. What "written against" means is how to [interpret citations within the extension specification](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Extension#How_to_read). Extensions are basically diff files; they say what to change in some particular specification. [See this answer for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546881/9547773#9547773).